# Rename python duplicate tuples in a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, duplicates, tuples

Given a list of tuples:

```
[("heat", 200), ("time", "15:00"), ("time", "16:00")]
```

how could I get following result by renaming duplicate "keys" of tuples.

```
[("heat", 200), ("time1", "15:00"), ("time2", "16:00")]
```

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to solve a problem is to break into multiple sub-problems. For starters

Firstly You may want to separate out "keys":

```
keys = [i[0] for i in lst]
keys
>>> ['heat', 'time', 'time']
```

Then you might wanna count how many times a key appears:

```
counts = {key: keys.count(key) for key in [i[0] for i in lst]}
counts
>>> {'heat': 1, 'time': 2}
```

Thirdly you might want to loop over and rename whatever keys appear twice:

```
for idx, key in enumerate(keys):
    if counts.get(key) and counts.get(key) > 1:
        for num in range(counts[key]):
            if key+str(num+1) not in keys:
                keys.remove(key) 
                keys.insert(idx+num, key+str(num+1))
keys
>>> ['heat', 'time1', 'time2']
```

Then you can simply combine these modified keys with your values to have desired output:

```
list(zip(keys,[i[1] for i in lst]))
>>> [('heat', 200), ('time1', '15:00'), ('time2', '16:00')]
```

There could be more efficient methods if you make use of libraries but this is how you approach this (or for argument sake any) problem by splitting it into multiple sub-problems.